# Creating NSDate from current date is incorrect

Tags: ios, nsdate

I'm sure I'm doing this wrong, but I basically want to create something similar to Apple's alarm clock.  So I have a UIDatePicker that shows the hours and minutes only.  My plan is to grab the hour and minute from the UIDatePicker, then create a UILocalNotification for that hour and minute for the current date or next date depending on if the alarm is available for that day or not.  So what I try to do when my view loads is this:

```
[self.alarmsDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerDidSelect:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.alarmsDatePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];

    // Get the current calendar
    self.calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    self.dateFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

    // Get the time portion of the datePicker's date
    NSDateComponents *timeComponentsSelectedDate = [_calendar components:_dateFlags fromDate:self.alarmsDatePicker.date];
    NSDate *timeOnlySelectedDate = [_calendar dateFromComponents:timeComponentsSelectedDate];
    self.startDate = timeOnlySelectedDate;
```

What I don't understand when I step through the code is, the datePicker gets the current time to start correctly.  But when I get to timeOnlySelectedDate, the date is 2001-01-01.  Why is that?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `_dateFlags` only include hour and minute. You should set your `_dateFlags` like this: `self.dateFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit`.